# c# - Expression overload as parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, overloading, func

I'd like to find a way to pass an expression (compiled if possible) as an argument to a function.
The expression will always return the same type. I want to save that expression(function) as a parameter.

A (short) example would be really appreciate if possible. :-)
I don't know if it is possible.

More info: Input is an expression where only the return type should be fixed. I need a way to define this kind of prototype.

Method call example:

```
public delegate double[] ValueRetreiverFunc(params object[] anyNumberOfParams);

public class Class1
{
    public double[] Func()
    {
        double[] values = new double[1];
        values[0] = 2.0;
        return values;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public double[] Func(int n)
    {
        double[] values = new double[n];
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            values[c] = 3.0;
        }
        return values;
    }
}

public class ClassTest
{
    public ValueRetreiverFunc ValueRetreiverFunc { get; set; }

    public void SetValueRetreiverFunc(ValueRetreiverFunc valueRetreiverFunc)
    {
        ValueRetreiverFunc = valueRetreiverFunc;
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        ClassTest classTest = new ClassTest();
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        classTest.SetValueRetreiverFunc(()=> class1.Func());
        DoProcessArrayOfDouble(classTest.ValueRetreiverFunc());

        classTest.SetValueRetreiverFunc(()=> class2.Func(7));
        DoProcessArrayOfDouble(classTest.ValueRetreiverFunc());
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be better off inspecting the method with reflection, as you can provide a dynamic array of parameters easily there.

Comment: So, you're saying you want to be able to pass Func() or Func(int) to the method as the same parameter?

Comment: To aswyer : Thanks, I will probably do that. But I wonder if the class Expression would not be fine for that ?

Comment: To Tejs : Partly right. Kind of. I think it is more than that. It's more an expression because the value of the parameter is fixed on assignment. It's probably my sample that is not enough good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve the problem that my collegue Omar show me... 
Simply with delegate... Due to lambda resolution by the compiler...

```
public class TestDelegate
{
    public delegate double[] ValueRetreiverFunc();
    // or  public Func<double[]> ValueRetreiverFunc;

    public class Class1
    {
        public double[] Func()
        {
            double[] values = new double[1];
            values[0] = 2.0;
            return values;
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        public double[] Func(int n)
        {
            double[] values = new double[n];
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
            {
                values[c] = 3.0;
            }

            return values;
        }
    }

    public class ClassTest
    {
        public ValueRetreiverFunc ValueRetreiverFunc { get; set; }

        public void SetValueRetreiverFunc(ValueRetreiverFunc valueRetreiverFunc)
        {
            ValueRetreiverFunc = valueRetreiverFunc;
        }

        public static void Test()
        {
            ClassTest classTest = new ClassTest();
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            Class2 class2 = new Class2();

            classTest.SetValueRetreiverFunc(() => class1.Func());
            DoProcessArrayOfDouble(classTest.ValueRetreiverFunc());
            classTest.SetValueRetreiverFunc(() => class2.Func(7));
            DoProcessArrayOfDouble(classTest.ValueRetreiverFunc());
        }

        static void DoProcessArrayOfDouble(double[] doubleArray)
        {
            foreach (double d in doubleArray)
            {
                Debug.Print(d.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to far. I only have to use "Func". It works like a charm.
This is my sample corrected...

```
public class Class1
{
    public double[] GetValues()
    {
        double[] values = new double[1];
        values[0] = 2.0;
        return values;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public double[] GetValues(int n)
    {
        double[] values = new double[n];
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            values[c] = 3.0;
        }
        return values;
    }
}

public class ClassTest
{
    public Func<double[]> ValueRetreiverFunc;


    public void SetValueRetreiverFunc(Func<double[]> valueRetreiverFunc)
    {
        ValueRetreiverFunc = valueRetreiverFunc;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        ClassTest classTest = new ClassTest();
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        classTest.SetValueRetreiverFunc(() => class1.GetValues());
        DoProcessArrayOfDouble(classTest.ValueRetreiverFunc());

        classTest.SetValueRetreiverFunc(() => class2.GetValues(7));
        DoProcessArrayOfDouble(classTest.ValueRetreiverFunc());
    }

    static void DoProcessArrayOfDouble(double[] doubleArray)
    {
        foreach(double d in doubleArray)
        {
            Debug.Print(d.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is like so - instead of trying to use a delegate, define an interface and each implementation returns whatever it wants.

```
public interface IDoubleReturningClass
{
     double[] DoSomething(params object[] anyNumberOfParams);
}

public class Class1 : IDoubleReturningClass
{
     public double[] DoSomething(params object[] anyNumberOfParams)
     {
         double[] values = new double[1];
         values[0] = 2.0;
         return values;
     }
}

public class Class2 : IDoubleReturningClass
{
     public double[] DoSomething(params object[] anyNumberOfParams)
     {
         double[] values = new double[n];
         for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
         {
             values[c] = 3.0;
         }
         return values;
     }
}

public class ClassTest
{
      public double[] Values { get; set; }

      public void SetValues(IDoubleReturningClass item)
      {
             Values = item.DoSomething( /* Your Params */);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tejs. I thought about it. But interface could not do the job. It is due to the fact that the expression is defined with a fixed value at a moment in time but should be the same anytime we recall this function. Interface could not remember the value. Just an expression can (Lambda or other kind).